# A POST doesn't return anything if the server takes a very long time to return. Client is running on AWS going to a nginx reverse proxy on local

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, post

I have a docker container running a python app on an EC2 that sends a post request to a server on our local network. On the local network there is a nginx reverse proxy that forwards the post request to the right server.

Problem: is that if the post takes a long time to return(20min), it doesn't return anything at all, even though I see the server sending a 200 response, and I see the 200 response on the nginx logs.

If the post takes a little bit to return, like under 2 min it works fine, and returns a 200 with payload.

If I run this same test locally, it returns fine, so I assume its something to do with the nginx reverse proxy or aws

There isn't any errors on the nginx logs.

I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot this.

Client side:

```
with open(reference, 'rb') as a, open(candidate, 'rb') as b:
        form = encoder.MultipartEncoder({
            'user': username,
            'password': password,
            'configname': config_name,
            'jobid': jobid,
            'reference': (os.path.basename(reference), a, 'application/pdf'),
            'candidate': (os.path.basename(candidate), b, 'application/pdf')
        })
        headers = {"Content-Type": form.content_type}
        r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=form, verify=False)
```

nginx reverse proxy

```
server {
        listen                  1234 ssl;
        server_name             name.com;

        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        include snippets/ssl.conf;

        gzip on;

        client_max_body_size 0;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        set $dest $http_destination;


        location /someserver {
                return 302 /someserver/;
        }

        location /someserver/ {

                set $dest $http_destination;

                if ($http_destination ~ "^https://(.+)") {
                        set $dest http://$1;
                }

                proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:5678/;
                

        }
}
```

logs from the reverse proxy, after it sees a response:

```
5.6.7.8 - - [14/Feb/2022:11:51:21 -0500] "POST /someserver/server/rest/app/dojob/submit HTTP/1.1" 200 2077 "-" "python-requests/2.27.1"
```

Comment: Intrigued to understand what kind of synchronous request would reasonably take 20 minutes.

Comment: It's a large pdf compare. Usually posts takes a couple minutes max, but this one is just very large.